# find values that don't have a pair from 2 columns in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

So I have an excel file that has 2 columns with different amount of values in them (all values start with "zk/" either lower or upper case). Example:

```
    a       |      b
zk/123456   | zk/987654321
zk/523423   | zk/123456
zk/987654321|
```

I want to find every single value that doesn't have a pair in the other column and write that in the **C** column in the excel workbook. So Here the only value that would be written in the **C** column is `zk/523423`. Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import * # library for excel

print("file name: ")
name = input()

try:
    wb = load_workbook(name + ".xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
except:
    print("Document doesn't exist, it isn't a .xlsx document or is not in the same directory as the program")
    exit()
    
ai = 1 # size of column a
while ws['A' + str(ai)].value != None:
    ai += 1

bi = 1 # size of column b
while ws['B' + str(bi)].value != None:
    bi += 1

a = [] # list of column a
b = [] # list of column b
x = [] # list of files that don't have a pair

for i in range(1, ai): 
    a.append(str(ws['A' + str(i)].value).lower()) # getting all files from column a 
    
for i in range(1, bi):
    b.append(str(ws['B' + str(i)].value).lower()) # getting all files from column b
    
#----Works fine until this point----

for i in a:
    if i not in b and i not in x: # finding files that dont have a pair in column b
        x.append(i)
        
for i in b:
    if i not in a and i not in x: # finding files that dont have a pair in column a
        x.append(i)
        
ws['C1'] = "values without pairs:" 
c = 2
for i in x:
    ws['C' + str(c)] = i # writing values that don't have a pair
    c += 1
    
wb.save(name + "_odvojeno.xlsx") # saving the document
print("document saved as " + name + "_edited.xlsx")
```

this code writes every single value from both the columns. I could replace this with just 2 for loops that write each element of column **A** and **B** and the result will be the same. In my example you will see:

```
    a       |      b       |     c
zk/123456   | zk/987654321 | zk/987654321
zk/523423   | zk/123456    | zk/123456
zk/987654321|              | zk/123456
                           | zk/523423
                           | zk/987654321
```

I have no idea why my code doesn't work. Can someone help?

EDIT TO EXPLAIN BETTER:

With "pair" I mean that some value exists in both columns. In my example I would like only **zk/523423** to be in column **C** since value of **zk/523423** exists only in 1 column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little bit of ambiguity in your question. So, I will address both cases.

1. As per your data, you have values in column A and column B. If there is no data in column B, you want the data in column A to be written to column C
2. In the question you have also mentioned '*that doesn't have a pair*'. As per this, even if column B has data and column A is blank, you want the data in column B to be written to column C, I think.

So, the below code will do both. If requirement-2 is not required you can remove the second if statement and it should be fine.

**Initial Data**

```
zk/123456        | zk/987654321
zk/523423        | zk/123456
zk/987654321     | 
zk/123456        | zk/987654321
zk/523423        | zk/123456
                 | zk/987654321
```

**The code**

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx') ## Open your file
ws=wb['Sheet1']  ## Open the required sheet
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row): ## For each row that has data, loop
    # Condition 1 - Loop through each row and see if col B is blank/None
    if ws.cell(row[0].row, 2).value is None: 
            ws.cell(row[0].row, 3).value = ws.cell(row[0].row, 1).value #Move cell A value to cell C

    # Condition 2 - Loop through each row and see if col A is blank/None - remove if not required
    if ws.cell(row[0].row, 1).value is None:
            ws.cell(row[0].row, 3).value = ws.cell(row[0].row, 2).value #Move cell B value to cell C
    
wb.save('yourfile.xlsx') ## Save and exit
```

**Output excel after processing**

[image]

**EDIT - Based on clarification provided**

The updated code is below. Note that this will first get column B into a list, iterate through each element in column A and see if there is a match. If NOT, it will add it to column C. Hope this is what you are looking for...

**data**
Same as what you have in the question

**Code**

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']
mylist = []

for col in ws['B']: #Read col B
    mylist.append(col.value)
    print(col.value)

i=1
for col in ws['A']:  #Check with col A and write to col C
     if col.value not in mylist:
        ws.cell(i, 3).value = col.value
        i = i+1

wb.save('myfile.xlsx')
```

**Excel after processing**

[image]

Comment: I don't think I explained it the best. With "pair"  I meant the same value exists somewhere in the other column. In your example what I want to be in column c is going to b: zk/523423 since it doesn't exist in the other column

Comment: Added updated code below existing answer. Please check EDIT section

Comment: so it turns out that the problem was the excel. For whatever reason all the vales had a random amount of whitespace behind them so all I had to do was add the '.strip()' method, silly me. Either way thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats great. Good to hear the issue was resolved